# Printing Class Name with Text in Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print class name with all options. For wrong answers its just **radio-button-click-target** but with the correct option its **radio-button-click-target correctquestions**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
addresses = ['https://www.ilmkidunya.com/online-test/5th-class-science-english-meduim-mcqs-with-answers?startfrom=0&last=92']
subjects = ['05th-Science-EM-']
for runscript in range(0, len(addresses)):
    response = requests.get(addresses[runscript])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    ques_id = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-title')
    ques_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-desc')
    optn_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='choose-answer-block')
    for i in range(0, len(ques_id)):
        unformated_ques_id = (ques_id[i].text)
        formated_ques_id = unformated_ques_id.replace("Question #  ", subjects[runscript])
        print(formated_ques_id)
        #print('\n')
        print(str(ques_det[i].text).strip())
        #print('\n')
        options = optn_det[i].find_all('label', class_='radio-button-click-target')
        for opn in options:
            print(str(opn.text).strip())
            #print('\n')
        print('<----->')
```

**Current Result**

05th-Science-EM-1

Female dengue mosquito lay eggs:

on wall

in soil

on wood

in water

<----->

05th-Science-EM-2

Snake is an example of:

vertebrates

worms

insects

snails

<----->

**Expected Result**

05th-Science-EM-1

Female dengue mosquito lay eggs:

radio-button-click-target: on wall

radio-button-click-target: in soil

radio-button-click-target: on wood

radio-button-click-target correctquestions: in water

<----->

05th-Science-EM-2

Snake is an example of:

radio-button-click-target correctquestions: vertebrates

radio-button-click-target: worms

radio-button-click-target: insects

radio-button-click-target: snails

<----->

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector as follows and remove the str calls on already strings. Also, use ['class'] to extract the class, where appropriate, and I use `join` to combine multi-valued classes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

addresses = ['https://www.ilmkidunya.com/online-test/5th-class-science-english-meduim-mcqs-with-answers?startfrom=0&last=92']
subjects = ['05th-Science-EM-']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for runscript in range(0, len(addresses)):
        response = s.get(addresses[runscript])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        ques_id = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-title')
        ques_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-desc')
        optn_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='choose-answer-block')

        for i in range(0, len(ques_id)):
            unformated_ques_id = (ques_id[i].text)
            formated_ques_id = unformated_ques_id.replace("Question #  ", subjects[runscript])
            print(formated_ques_id)
            print(ques_det[i].text.strip())
            options = optn_det[i].select('label.radio-button-click-target')

            for opn in options:
                print(' '.join(opn['class']), opn.text.strip())
            print('<----->')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have tried a little more.

```
for opn in options:
            print(' '.join(opn['class']), end=' : ')
            print(str(opn.text).strip())
```

This will get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code include multiple errors:

1. You don't need to keep call `soup` object multiple times! as you can pickup your `goal` and then parse it.
2. You don't need to use two functions if you can use one function. Something like `.text.strip()` is actually can be handled all in one via `.get_text(strip=True)`!
3. there's many errors but just move to my code so you can get the full idea.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = soup.select_one('#divQuestion1')

    title = goal.select_one('.q-desc').get_text(strip=True)
    can = goal.select_one(
        'label[class$=correctquestions]').get_text(strip=True)
    wan = [x.get_text(strip=True)
           for x in goal.select('label[class$=click-target]')]
    print("Question: {}\nCorrect-Answer: {}\nWrong-Answers: {}".format(title, can, wan))


main('https://www.ilmkidunya.com/online-test/5th-class-science-english-meduim-mcqs-with-answers?startfrom=0&last=92')
```

Comment: get_text() does multiple calls under the hood btw https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/element.py

Comment: @QHarr That's not the main meaning which i refer to it. The underneath class is actually operating within one place in the memory. So i meant if we are calling 2 functions from outside so we actually load two places into the memory.